# How do I get a Jitterbit hosted HTTP Endpoint [servername] and [port]?

Tags: wsdl, listener, endpoint, server-name, jitterbit

I am creating an operation in Jitterbit containing a Hosted HTTP Endpoint. It should listen to a SFDC outbound message. Before you can download the SFDC WSDL, it requires you to map out the listening servername and port (jitterbit).  As a matter of fact, Jitterbit will require it when the WSDL is imported.

I read the articles at 
*http://support.jitterbit.com/communityarticles?type=documentation&cat=Hosted_HTTP_Endpoints*

All it mentions is:

- Endpoint URL: The URL you want this end-point to listen to. E.g. if you enter "company/po_import" the end-point will be triggered when the URL "http://[server name]:[server port]/company/po_import" is requested.

Is there a way to get this url from Jitterbit?  Or do I have to purchase a license to be handed a server/port combo ?

This question has already been asked,  but got no replies..
[JItterBit HTTP Endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20571637/jitterbit-http-endpoint)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

By popular opinion, the port appears to be 46908. According to @JimRae,  the servername is the outside facing dns or IP of the computer where the Jitterbit agent is running for this project !

Edit: Straight from the horses mouth: The Jitterbit Listener runs from the computer where you installed the Jitterbit Agent, IF you installed the agent. Preferably the computer with the Full Jitterbit software.